# How to create an index of songs in the Songs package using Texmaker?

Tags: latex, texmaker

I cannot install the package with the MikTex setup and I have tried to add some "own" songs to the sample document, as instructed in the guide. My songs and authors do not get included though - even if I build more than once.

How do I (from scratch) get an index of songs (maybe also authors) included in my document? And while we are at it, how do I include a table of contents that contains the song sections and an ordered list of the songs in each song section, in order as they appear in the song book?

I have the following structure of the tex file:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside,article, landscape, twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lyric]{songs}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}


\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{4.1in}
\settowidth{\versenumwidth}{1.\ }
\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}

\begin{songs}{}


\beginsong{Velkommen igen, Guds engle små}
    [by={N F S Grundtvig, A P Berggreen}]
    \beginverse
        Velkommen igen, Guds engle små,
        ...
    \endverse
    
    \beginverse
        Velkommen igen, Guds engle små,
        ...
    \endverse
    
    \beginverse
        Vor hytte er lav og så vor dør,
        ...
    \endverse
\endsong

\beginsong{Dejlig er den himmel blå}[by={Louis Bourgeois and Thomas Ken},
                 sr={Revelation 5:13},
                 cr={Public domain.}]
    \beginverse
    Dejlig er den himmel blå
    ... 
    \endverse
    \beginchorus
      Os fra jorden op til sig
      Os fra jorden op til sig
    \endchorus
\endsong

 \end{songs}

 \end{document}
```

Based on that how do I get a list of songs in the order of appearance in the document, like:

1. Velkommen igen, Guds engle små
2. Dejlig er den himmelblå

and at the end of the document, an index with the songs by alphabetical order, with page numbers

Comment: Can you please make a [mre] instead of just a code fragment?

Comment: Sure - the "songs" are included using "\input{salmer}" in my original setup, but for ease of overview, a "full" document is included. The output I get is numbered songs, with the Song section text before the songs, as it should be, but have no clue, on how to get indexing and table of contents working in this environment